# Setting up OpenCMIS InMemory Repository

Tags: java, maven, cmis, opencmis, apache-chemistry

I´m trying to set up the OpenCMIS InMemory Repository following the instructions from [Apache](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/repositories/dev-repositories-inmemory.html) but I keep getting the following error when running the maven command `mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true`:

```
    [INFO] 4 errors
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Reactor Summary:
    [INFO]
    [INFO] Apache Chemistry OpenCMIS ......................... SUCCESS [1.665s]
    [INFO] OpenCMIS Commons API .............................. SUCCESS [3.327s]
    [INFO] OpenCMIS Commons Implementation ................... SUCCESS [7.599s]
    [INFO] OpenCMIS Client API ............................... SUCCESS [0.714s]
    [INFO] OpenCMIS Client Bindings Implementation ........... FAILURE [2.285s]
    [INFO] OpenCMIS Client Implementation .................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] OpenCMIS Server Support ........................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] OpenCMIS Server Implementation .................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] OpenCMIS Server Implementation WAR packaging ...... SKIPPED
    [INFO] OpenCMIS Test Utilities ........................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] OpenCMIS InMemory Server WAR packaging ............ SKIPPED
    [INFO] OpenCMIS FileShare Server Implementation .......... SKIPPED
    [INFO] OpenCMIS JCR Server Implementation ................ SKIPPED
    [INFO] OpenCMIS Server Archetype ......................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] OpenCMIS Bridge WAR packaging ..................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] OpenCMIS Test Compatibility Kit ................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] OpenCMIS Full Integration Tests ................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] OpenCMIS Tools .................................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] OpenCMIS Browser .................................. SKIPPED
    [INFO] OpenCMIS Browser Application ...................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] OpenCMIS Workbench ................................ SKIPPED
    [INFO] OpenCMIS OSGi Client Wrapper ...................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] OpenCMIS Android Client ........................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] OpenCMIS Assemblies Distribution .................. SKIPPED
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 16.533s
    [INFO] Finished at: Thu May 08 18:42:47 CEST 2014
    [INFO] Final Memory: 33M/63M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [WARNING] The requested profile "redhat-techpreview-all-repository" could not be
     activated because it does not exist.
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.
    5.1:compile (default-compile) on project chemistry-opencmis-client-bindings: Com
    pilation failure: Compilation failure:
    [ERROR] C:\Users\xtdell72\Desktop\chemistry-opencmis-0.11.0\chemistry-opencmis-c
    lient\chemistry-opencmis-client-bindings\src\main\java\org\apache\chemistry\open
    cmis\client\bindings\spi\webservices\SunJREPortProvider.java:[41,40] cannot find
     symbol
    [ERROR] symbol  : class StreamingAttachmentFeature
    [ERROR] location: package com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer
    [ERROR] C:\Users\xtdell72\Desktop\chemistry-opencmis-0.11.0\chemistry-opencmis-c
    lient\chemistry-opencmis-client-bindings\src\main\java\org\apache\chemistry\open
    cmis\client\bindings\spi\webservices\SunJREPortProvider.java:[65,28] cannot find
     symbol
    [ERROR] symbol  : class StreamingAttachmentFeature
    [ERROR] location: class org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.webser
    vices.SunJREPortProvider
    [ERROR] C:\Users\xtdell72\Desktop\chemistry-opencmis-0.11.0\chemistry-opencmis-c
    lient\chemistry-opencmis-client-bindings\src\main\java\org\apache\chemistry\open
    cmis\client\bindings\spi\webservices\SunJREPortProvider.java:[115,66] cannot fin
    d symbol
    [ERROR] symbol  : variable CONNECT_TIMEOUT
    [ERROR] location: interface com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.JAXWSProperties
    [ERROR] C:\Users\xtdell72\Desktop\chemistry-opencmis-0.11.0\chemistry-opencmis-c
    lient\chemistry-opencmis-client-bindings\src\main\java\org\apache\chemistry\open
    cmis\client\bindings\spi\webservices\SunJREPortProvider.java:[120,66] cannot fin
    d symbol
    [ERROR] symbol  : variable REQUEST_TIMEOUT
    [ERROR] location: interface com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.JAXWSProperties
    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
    ch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
    d the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureExc
    eption
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command

    [ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :chemistry-opencmis-client-bindings
```

Now, I guess the error (at least some of them as `[ERROR] symbol  : variable CONNECT_TIMEOUT`) is because it's not finding the JAX-WS libraries, but since I just downloaded the code and followed instructions, I can't see what I can do to solve it or where to add the dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to build the development version, which is not always stable.

If you just want to use the InMemory Repository, download the "OpenCMIS Server Webapps" package from https://chemistry.apache.org/java/download.html .

Answer (score 1):

You should check your maven version. The Apache site says that version 2.2.1 is required, against java 1.5.